# Styling columns of items without akward spacing between rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have to make a set of checkboxes, of any number, arranged in columns.  I can't seem to figure out how to do that without specifying a height so I used flexbox to make rows instead, but that won't work when there items with multiple lines of text.  This will create vertical spacing which I don't want.  Is there any clean suggestion to fix this? In the screengrab I show where I am at now, the spacing between each field vertically should be uniform.

```
.filter-fields-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 350px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.filter-fields-container  > .field {
  flex: 1 0 33%;
}
```

.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputLorem" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" /> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputConsectetur" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Consectetur adipisicing elit" /> <span>Consectetur adipisicing elit</span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputIpsa" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Ipsa eligendi doloremque reiciendis laboriosam deleniti officia" /> <span>Ipsa eligendi doloremque reiciendis laboriosam deleniti officia</span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputAd" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Ad natus optio" /> <span>Ad natus optio </span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputMaxime" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Maxime ipsam quas culpa commodi" /> <span>Maxime ipsam quas culpa commodi</span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputAccusamus" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Accusamus quam dolorum error" /> <span>Accusamus quam dolorum error</span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputNumquam" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Numquam modi" /> <span>Numquam modi</span> </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Checboxes styled by flex]

Comment: You get that behaviour with any layout method not just flexbox if you don't define a div height...in fact it's expected.

Comment: How about this option with `columns` and `tables` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/17/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try `column-fill`:

```css
.container {
  -webkit-column-count:3;
     -moz-column-count:3;
          column-count:3;
  -webkit-column-fill:balance;
     -moz-column-fill:balance;
          column-fill:balance;
  width:100%;
}
.field {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}

/* extra ? */
input {
  float:left;
  }
span {
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputLorem" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" /> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputConsectetur" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Consectetur adipisicing elit" /> <span>Consectetur adipisicing elit</span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputIpsa" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Ipsa eligendi doloremque reiciendis laboriosam deleniti officia" /> <span>Ipsa eligendi doloremque reiciendis laboriosam deleniti officia</span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputAd" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Ad natus optio" /> <span>Ad natus optio </span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputMaxime" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Maxime ipsam quas culpa commodi" /> <span>Maxime ipsam quas culpa commodi</span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputAccusamus" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Accusamus quam dolorum error" /> <span>Accusamus quam dolorum error</span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputNumquam" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Numquam modi" /> <span>Numquam modi</span> </label>
  </div> <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputLorem" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" /> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputConsectetur" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Consectetur adipisicing elit" /> <span>Consectetur adipisicing elit</span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputIpsa" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Ipsa eligendi doloremque reiciendis laboriosam deleniti officia" /> <span>Ipsa eligendi doloremque reiciendis laboriosam deleniti officia</span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputAd" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Ad natus optio" /> <span>Ad natus optio </span> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputMaxime" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Maxime ipsam quas culpa commodi" /> <span>Maxime ipsam quas culpa commodi</span> </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

result is most of the time average output desired [codepen to play with, *(add/remove elements)*](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VegWrV)

---

for flex, you need to set a width and allow elements to wrap down , it will fill up row by row and not columns by columns.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.field {
  width: 33%;
}
/* extra ? */

input {
  float: left;
}
span {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputLorem" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" /> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span> 
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputConsectetur" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Consectetur adipisicing elit" /> <span>Consectetur adipisicing elit</span> 
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputIpsa" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Ipsa eligendi doloremque reiciendis laboriosam deleniti officia" /> <span>Ipsa eligendi doloremque reiciendis laboriosam deleniti officia</span> 
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputAd" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Ad natus optio" /> <span>Ad natus optio </span> 
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputMaxime" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Maxime ipsam quas culpa commodi" /> <span>Maxime ipsam quas culpa commodi</span> 
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputAccusamus" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Accusamus quam dolorum error" /> <span>Accusamus quam dolorum error</span> 
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputNumquam" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Numquam modi" /> <span>Numquam modi</span> 
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputLorem" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" /> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span> 
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputConsectetur" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Consectetur adipisicing elit" /> <span>Consectetur adipisicing elit</span> 
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputIpsa" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Ipsa eligendi doloremque reiciendis laboriosam deleniti officia" /> <span>Ipsa eligendi doloremque reiciendis laboriosam deleniti officia</span> 
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputAd" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Ad natus optio" /> <span>Ad natus optio </span> 
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>
      <input class="input-checkbox" id="InputMaxime" name="Inputs" type="checkbox" value="Maxime ipsam quas culpa commodi" /> <span>Maxime ipsam quas culpa commodi</span> 
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh this is new, thank you, I will test now and get back with an answered or not

Comment: @MichaelF  for the flex option, you need to set width and allow wrapping (second snippet in answer) it will drawn row by rows and won't dispatch column by column .

Answer (score 0):

```
.filter-fields-container  > .field {
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  height:50px;
}
```

Height is nedded.
You classes or not the same in html as in css.